# margin auto 0 not working on ipad safari?

Tags: html, ipad, responsive-design

Hello I have a lot of trouble finding a way to center a div in safari on ipad...this works in chrome on ipad but safari doesn't scale in landscape format...the are margins on the left and right but i got to scroll all over the whole thing. Any ideas to make this work in both browsers..chrome and safari?

HTML:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

    </head>  
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

            </div>

    </body>  
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    background-color: black;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do this. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9PGhg/4/)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">

            </div>
        </div>                 
    </div>    
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

.outer{
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.inner{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

​.content{
    width:90%;
    height:90%; 
    background:red;  
    display:inline-block;    
}​
```

Comment: did you try it on your ipad?...in my case i have still the box having an oversize so that i have to scroll to the the right margin...

Comment: I tried in it ipad safari using http://jsfiddle.net/9PGhg/4/show/ and it works in both landscape and portrait. And I am pretty sure it will work in chrome too

Comment: Take a screen shot and send a link

Comment: i got it...you are right...jsfiddle.net/9PGhg/4/show  is working

Comment: There is a 100% height bug in firefox.. As soon as you add content to your `div.content` you will see the content and the box.

Comment: You could use javascript to fix this problem in firefox. Do you want me to make an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you're defining your `width` to be `90%`, you can avoid the issue and simply set `margin: 0 5%;`

Comment: sorrry edit: the black box appears but scaling is like before